# List in eventlist - something wrong, perhaps missing \item

Tags: lists, itemize, cv

writing a cv but its not formatting as desired and creating errors.

MWE (link to `tccv` https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv):

[image]

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\part{Sam Harper}

\section{Professional experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{September 2017 -- Present}
 {UoB Quants, Persici Ltd}
 {Quantitative Analyst}

\begin{itemize}

\item Completed the build and maintenance of current portfolio optimiser.\\
\item Time series analysis and econometric and statistical arbitrage oppertunities.\\
\item Calculating risk and exposure for 5 equity portfolios.\\

\end{itemize}

\end{eventlist

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please give us a link to the used class `tccv`?

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the second nested environment `itemize` is not allowed in that class.

But here is a simple workaround ( I added `\textbullet` and deleted the wrong `itemize`):

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\part{Sam Harper}

\section{Professional experience}

\begin{eventlist}
\item{September 2017 -- Present}
 {UoB Quants, Persici Ltd}
 {Quantitative Analyst}

  \textbullet~Completed the build and maintenance of current portfolio optimiser. % <==================================
  \textbullet~Time series analysis and econometric and statistical arbitrage oppertunities. 
  \textbullet~Calculating risk and exposure for 5 equity portfolios. 

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.
\end{eventlist}

\end{document}
```

It gives the result:

[image: resulting pdf]